# How to prevent CSRF attack in a legacy Java application?

Tags: java, csrf

I'm working on a 12+ year old Java Web application. It follows client's unique framework and not any of the industry standard framework! Recently an Appscan report was generated for the application, as per which this application is having highly critical security problems like it is prone to CSRF, SQL Injection etc.

Now I have to implement something purely in Java, without using any framework and get rid of this CSRF Attack. I did some google and came to know that we have to append a temporary token in the URL and then validate it. Is it the only way. I couldn't get much practical solutions.

Anyone experienced in dealing with such a scenario? Please Help me!

Comment: Any kind of implementing the feature is highly dependent on the framework. I think you should provide details about how are get requests and forms are handled by the fw.

Comment: Hi @SeyfülislamÖzdemir , We are using simple servlets for request processing.

Comment: Any common functions available that are called for every get request and form generation/submission?

Comment: All the requests will first go to a servlet which is part of the framework. We cannot modify this! And this servlet decides which action method is to be called!

Comment: So I think you have to go through all of the actions and make them call a function to do the pre/post processing work for you. Try to implement a function and then call the function inside method bodies that are called by the servlet.

Comment: What should be done in this Pre/post processor? Can you share any good implementation links? I'm new to this CSRF.

Comment: You can send a form object (if you have a wrapper in the backend) and make the function to add a hidden csrf token field in the preprocessor. The post processor would get the token from the form and check if it was the one sent previously.

Comment: You mean to say, in the form bean, I should have a randomly generated hidden token? And when user do some action, before processing the action, i should validate the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  best way to prevent CSRF attacks is to add a randomly generated token to every response rendered from the server. The token is than retrieved and checked in the next request received at the server.If the token does not match than there is possibility of CSRF attack.

Since you are using servlets , you can use servlet filter to achieve this functionality.You can write your CSRF token check functionality in `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)` method.

Generally CSRF attacks related threats are resolved using some security framework like Spring Security .

Comment: Hi @AtulSharma, I cannot modify the Servlets. They are part of the framework.

Comment: I think you do not need to modify servlets. What you need to is to create a filter class that implements Filter interface and make entry for filter in web.xml file.

Comment: Hi @AtulSharma, Is this what you are talking about? http://java.dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-java-web-apps

Comment: Yes I was talking about that only

Comment: Thanks @AtulSharma, Let me try that :)

Comment: @PraveeshP. You are welcome. If you think this is the answer you seek, then you should close the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any other way of doing this? Do you know any?

Comment: Yes there are other methods to this thing but that will require implementation of some framework which I think is not feasible in your case.

Comment: I can use OWASP to implement this. I didn't get much Idea on how to implement Owasp csrf guard, from the official site. I need an article  like: http://java.dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-java-web-apps , but using owasp. Can someone please help?